# Check number of active network connection iOS app makes

Tags: instruments

“Network Connection” instrument shows what are the network connections that app is making if we use “Connection Summary” in drop down menu.

a)  Does the connections that it shows are the total connections that app has made till now.
Or
b)  Does it shows the current total number of connections which are live at present.

If it is case #b, I think our app is making number of connections and is not cleaning it.
Can anyone answer if it is #a or #b ?

Comment: Also , if it is #a, how can we find out current total number of connections which are live at present ?